# Cannot accept licenses in Android (no prompt was given) after I re-installed Studio. Also flutter doctor --android-licenses gave JNI error

Tags: java, android, licensing

Error was: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/prefs/AndroidLocationsProvider has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

When I launched Android Studio after the re-installation, I never got a prompt to accept any license

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre
ln -s ../jre jdk
ln -s "/Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin" jdk
flutter doctor -v
```

For Mac users who are using JetBrains Toolbox, here is the

Answer (score 0):

**Windows:**

**1.** First check where is your java home path set by executing `echo %JAVA_HOME%` command in command prompt.

**example:**

```
echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Apps\Java\jdk7-x64
```

**2.** If the java version is lower than the Java11 then u need to download and install java version 11 or higher.

**Class file version example:**

```
class file version 45 = Java 1.1
class file version 46 = Java 1.2
class file version 47 = Java 1.3
class file version 48 = Java 1.4
class file version 49 = Java 5
class file version 50 = Java 6
class file version 51 = Java 7
class file version 52 = Java 8
class file version 53 = Java 9
class file version 54 = Java 10
class file version 55 = Java 11
class file version 56 = Java 12
class file version 57 = Java 13
```

**3.** Now go to 'Environment Variable' setting and in 'User variables' click New button and set `Varible name: JAVA_HOME` &  `Varible value: C:\Apps\Java\jdk11`(Put your jdk path).

**4.** Then inside User variables path, add a new path `%JAVA_HOME\bin`.

**5.** Now again open command prompt and execute `echo %JAVA_HOME%` command and check if the new path updated or not. If everything looks fine, then execute this `flutter doctor --android-licenses` command.